# TextView inside ViewPager intercepts touch events

Tags: android, view, textview, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that contains two fragments. In any of the fragments I can touch a place, swipe to switch to another `fragment`. One of the fragments contains a list. Items in the list contains one `TextView` and one `ImageView`. The issue is, if you dragging has been started from tapping the `ImageView`, it's OK. But if it's been from the `TextView`, the drag was never known to the `ViewPager`, as a result the 'smooth switching' never happens.

Any clue on this?

EDIT

This picture is to show how my GUI is. If the drag has been started from TextViewE, it doesn't begin.
[image]

Comment: You should post some code. There isn't anything special about `TextView` that overrides `ViewPager`.

Comment: @aneal see if the picture explains my idea better

Comment: This bugs me so much, I'd be glad to see the answer too. TextView's inside the ListView intercept touch, ViewPager became barely usable.

Comment: +1 for handmade picture!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This thing bothered me too, but I've managed to find the answer.

Basically, the case is: if the view can scroll horizontally, it intercepts the horizontal motion event and **ViewPager** is not able to process it anymore.

Since **API Level 14** TextViews have **android:scrollHorizontally** property (and **setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean)** method), which, if set to true, causes the TextView to intercept horizontal scroll motion events.

You may set it to false either in XML or right in the code, but *watch out*: **android:singleLine** property forces **android:scrollHorizontally** to be set to **true**! *Very tricky point*! But fortunately, you usually able to safely replace single line property with **android:maxLines="1"** and necessary **ellipsize** value.

Good luck!

Comment: Found the same problem and discovered that removing the singleLine statement solved. Just found out why :D. Thanks!

Comment: If I want to set marquee to the text view, i need to set singleLine to be true. Is there any way to avoid it and enable marquee too?

Comment: Wow, I have been spending the last 1.5 days trying to determine why my sporadically my ViewPager was not scrolling even though I could see its touch events firing. This answer saved me. Turns out I had a TextView with `singleLine=true` and this would halt the ViewPager scrolling. Since the TextView itself was a pretty big view the chances of the user trying to drag while over that view was pretty high - hence no scrolling. Removing `singleLine` was the final solution. Thanks again!

Comment: android:maxLines="1" worked for me as I needed to set ellipsize. Thanks for answering.

Comment: This got me most of the way to a solution but I found that for me I needed to set my text view to "match_parent" for width instead of "wrap_content" in addition to the android:scrollHorizontally.

Comment: great answer, also singleLine is deprecated, remember to use maxLines="1", thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

you can override onTouchEvent() of the TextView:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return false;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```