# can not scroll the ViewPager when touching TextView(with android:gravity="center") in it

Tags: android, textview

In my ViewPager, there was a ImageButton and TextView hold by LinearLayout, and now I change them to one TextView with coupound drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.iclinux.android.custom_views.NoScrollTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:iclinux="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_bg"
    style="@style/EllipsizedSingleLineTextView"
    android:textSize="@dimen/grid_item_title_size"
    >
</com.iclinux.android.custom_views.NoScrollTextView>
```

My question is: I can not flip left or right when touching the TextView, but if removed "android:gravity="center", it works... unfortunately, the text is not centered anyway...

```
public class NoScrollTextView extends TextView {

    public NoScrollTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            return false;
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

What happened here? thanks a lot.

Comment: An interesting bug that I come accross. Thank you. I gave you an up vote.

Comment: Just the same problem, Found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470755/textview-inside-viewpager-intercepts-touch-events)

Answer (score 21):

**`android:singleLine="true"`** forces **`android:scrollHorizontally`** to be set to true, and according to my tests only if you change **`android:gravity`** (i.e. default gravity seems not to give this problem).

I solved this issue in a TextView by simply replacing **`android:singleLine="true"`** with **`android:maxLines="1"`**

After this change, I had no more problems with the ViewPager. Now it is scrolling as expected while touching elements with **`android:gravity="right"`**.

Comment: OMG! I wasted two hours on a stupid problem like this and finally I found your answer which fixed it !! I can't believe Google puts these shitty bugs in.

Comment: OMG! This is Android in a nutshell.

Answer (score 10):

solved by overriding:

```
@TargetApi(14)
@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: God only knows why this isn't upvoted. This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got it done by doing:

```
textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this case. My solution;

I added `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` to the view in my XML, then I used `android:maxLines` instead of `android:singleLine` attribute. It works properly now.

The doc from the attrs.xml;

> @deprecated This attribute is deprecated. Use `maxLines`
>   instead to change  the layout of a static text, and use the
>   `textMultiLine` flag in the  inputType attribute instead
>   for editable text views (if both singleLine and inputType  are
>   supplied, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine).
>
> `<attr name="singleLine" format="boolean" />`