# Android ViewPager: Child Button prevents scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I have a ViewPager and a fragment containing a button. When I swipe on the button, the scroll doesn't work. It works outside the button area.

How do I make swipe function scroll and click/tap function perform action on the button?

Same code below:

Fragment1

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Add button"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_button_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19332457/4507915, when singleLine is set to true in combination of layout_gravity, android:scrollHorizontally is forced to true (regardless of your set).
You can use android:maxLines="1" instead of singleLine, and add android:ellipsize="end" if you need same ellipsize behavior. In alternative, you can override "canScrollHorizontally" of view to prevent this problem