# PagerSlidingTabStrip ViewPager not scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a PagerSlidingTabStrip with viewpager which holds three fragments. One of the fragment has ListView, When i swipe left or right on the ListView items the viewpager is not changing pages, when i swipe outside the ListView scrolling works fine. When i swipe on the other fragments which contains only TextView the swipe is working. Please suggest, What i might be doing wrong?

This issue can be reproduced just by adding the below fragment and adapter in the PagerSlidingTabStrip's sample code itself.

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = null;
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
            ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.homegrid);

            listview.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(inflater));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }
}

public class HomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public HomeAdapter( LayoutInflater inflater)
    {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_grid_item, parent, false);
        }
       TextView text1 =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        text1.setText("FAVOURITE "+position);

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffe0e0e0"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/homegrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

home_grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:background="#000000"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="FAVOUR"
        android:textSize="9pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It seems that the `ListView` overrides the `onTouch` event. Add code of the listview plz

Comment: If you don't add the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` what will happen then? 
A `ListView` should work perfectly fine with both `ViewPager` as well as the `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, so something is messing it up. You didn't change or enhance any of the sample code from Google? 
Also your `Fragment` is flawed - it probably doesn't have anything to do with this issue, but you should have a public constructor for the `Fragment` always.

Comment: And one more thing... the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` is not a default Android component - it's a 3rd party library - why don't you try with the `TabLayout` from the Design library? See this tutorial on how it works: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen I have not implemented any custom ListView. I am using the default android ListView.

Comment: @Darwind Its not working even without PagerSlidingTabStrip. I used the same code from github. I only added the HomeFragment and added in position 1. My client already has used PagerSlidingTabStrip in his app, we just tried to add a new fragment with listview and it was not scrolling, then i tried adding a new fragment with listview in sample code from github itself and there also its not working.  [Github Code](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/tree/master/sample)

Comment: Thanks for you help guys. The culprit seems to be         android:singleLine="true" in TextView of home_grid_item.xml. It seems strange everything started working after removing it. But i am not sure why.

Comment: Ok, that sounds weird - are you sure you didn't remove or changed anything else?

Comment: yes, i am sure. I even tried adding the  android:singleLine="true" back and scroll was not working again. You can try it in a simple viewpager itself. The issue is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager containing TextView with android:singleLine="true" is causing the issue.
The issue is already discussed and answered in the below question.

[can not scroll the ViewPager when touching TextView(with android:gravity="center") in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915040/can-not-scroll-the-viewpager-when-touching-textviewwith-androidgravity-center/19332457#19332457)